# Increasing Training/Validation Accuracy for Breast Mammography

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I've been training CNN model for binary classification task in order to classify Breast Mammography image patches to Normal and Abnormal. Here is my training plot:

[image]

Even though results are some what solid, for binary classification task I am aiming for `0.9` or more train/val accuracy. I've examined output from training, and it seems that network is stuck in a saddle point. Here is a sample from training output:

```
Epoch 48/400
134/134 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2837 - binary_accuracy: 0.8762
Epoch 00048: val_loss did not improve from 0.37938
134/134 [==============================] - 39s 294ms/step - loss: 0.2837 - binary_accuracy: 0.8762 - val_loss: 0.3802 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8358
Epoch 49/400
134/134 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2820 - binary_accuracy: 0.8846
Epoch 00049: val_loss did not improve from 0.37938
134/134 [==============================] - 39s 294ms/step - loss: 0.2820 - binary_accuracy: 0.8846 - val_loss: 0.3844 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8312
Epoch 50/400
134/134 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2835 - binary_accuracy: 0.8806
Epoch 00050: val_loss did not improve from 0.37938
134/134 [==============================] - 39s 292ms/step - loss: 0.2835 - binary_accuracy: 0.8806 - val_loss: 0.3827 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8293
Epoch 51/400
134/134 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2754 - binary_accuracy: 0.8843
Epoch 00051: val_loss did not improve from 0.37938
134/134 [==============================] - 39s 293ms/step - loss: 0.2754 - binary_accuracy: 0.8843 - val_loss: 0.3847 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8246
Epoch 52/400
134/134 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2773 - binary_accuracy: 0.8832
Epoch 00052: val_loss did not improve from 0.37938
134/134 [==============================] - 39s 290ms/step - loss: 0.2773 - binary_accuracy: 0.8832 - val_loss: 0.4020 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8293
Epoch 53/400
134/134 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2762 - binary_accuracy: 0.8825
Epoch 00053: val_loss did not improve from 0.37938
134/134 [==============================] - 39s 290ms/step - loss: 0.2762 - binary_accuracy: 0.8825 - val_loss: 0.3918 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8106
Epoch 54/400
134/134 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2734 - binary_accuracy: 0.8881
Epoch 00054: val_loss did not improve from 0.37938
134/134 [==============================] - 39s 290ms/step - loss: 0.2734 - binary_accuracy: 0.8881 - val_loss: 0.4216 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8181
Epoch 55/400
134/134 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2902 - binary_accuracy: 0.8804
Epoch 00055: val_loss improved from 0.37938 to 0.36383, saving model to /content/drive/My Drive/Breast Mammography/Patch Classifier/Training/normal-abnormal_patch_classification_weights_clr-055- 0.3638.hdf5
134/134 [==============================] - 40s 301ms/step - loss: 0.2902 - binary_accuracy: 0.8804 - val_loss: 0.3638 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8396
Epoch 56/400
134/134 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2766 - binary_accuracy: 0.8822
Epoch 00056: val_loss did not improve from 0.36383
134/134 [==============================] - 39s 291ms/step - loss: 0.2766 - binary_accuracy: 0.8822 - val_loss: 0.4408 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8209
Epoch 57/400
134/134 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2811 - binary_accuracy: 0.8790
Epoch 00057: val_loss did not improve from 0.36383
134/134 [==============================] - 39s 289ms/step - loss: 0.2811 - binary_accuracy: 0.8790 - val_loss: 0.3743 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8396
Epoch 58/400
134/134 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2834 - binary_accuracy: 0.8792
Epoch 00058: val_loss did not improve from 0.36383
134/134 [==============================] - 39s 289ms/step - loss: 0.2834 - binary_accuracy: 0.8792 - val_loss: 0.3946 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8200
Epoch 59/400
134/134 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2716 - binary_accuracy: 0.8797
Epoch 00059: val_loss did not improve from 0.36383
134/134 [==============================] - 39s 293ms/step - loss: 0.2716 - binary_accuracy: 0.8797 - val_loss: 0.3784 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8340
Epoch 60/400
134/134 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2755 - binary_accuracy: 0.8836
Epoch 00060: val_loss did not improve from 0.36383
134/134 [==============================] - 39s 290ms/step - loss: 0.2755 - binary_accuracy: 0.8836 - val_loss: 0.4015 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8321
Epoch 61/400
134/134 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2767 - binary_accuracy: 0.8827
Epoch 00061: val_loss did not improve from 0.36383
```

I am considering following options:

- Load network from epoch where learning has stopped and train it with **STEP learning rate schedule** (starting with big learning rate in order to escape saddle point)
- Perform offline augmentation to increase number of training data, while keeping all transformations performed during online augmentation
- Changing networks architecture (for now I am using custom, somewhat shallow (I would say semi-deep) model)

Does anyone have any suggestions other then the ones I've mentioned above. Also, I am using `SGD` with `momentum=0.9`. Are there any optimizers in practice that are able to escape saddle points more easily then SGD with momentum? Also, how does `BATCH_SIZE` (which I've set to `32`, while `TRAINING_SIZE=4300` - no class imbalance present)) affect learning?

Comment: The first thing I would look at is parameter count (call model.summary()). That's the most common cause of early convergence and the first thing I would try before getting too deep into the hyperparameters.

Comment: @markemus thank you for your comment. Could you please elaborate it a bit further? For example, when calling model.summary() I am having around 5.7 milion trainable parameteres. How exactly does this correlate with early convergance?

Comment: It very much depends on the architecture and the dataset, but in general more parameters = lower loss; up until a certain point, where you start getting overfitting (validation loss growing while training loss decreases). That's generally the first thing to play around with. Add some more features to your layers and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at the graph, it is mostly possible that the model is performing to its best considering the size of the dataset. Although the performance is not so bad, I would give the following suggestions:

1. Try a pre-trained model. The pre-trained model mostly works better in small and big datasets. You may use any pre-trained model architecture from Keras [applications](https://keras.io/api/applications/). To implement it properly, you should use `include_top=False`, and `weights='imagenet'`.
2. If you are not willing to change the model, then you may try training it in different image datasets, such as imagenet, mini-imagenet, tiny-imagenet. Pre-training may cause the model to find a more optimal embedding sub-space.
3. If you do not have any dropout layers in the current model, try adding some. This may cause an improvement in generalization.
4. `SGD` with `momentum=0.9` is a good choice. However, you may try `Adam` with `learning_rate=0.001`.
5. After selecting the best loss function, try having a search on different `batch_sizes`. I believe would notice some improvement with better peak accuracy.

I hope these answers would help you. If there are any more questions, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: These are all common suggestions and most of them I've tried, while the others are not applicable (such as transfer learning - even though there are papers that show promising result, there are papers that debunk using pretrained imagenet networks on medical image analysis tasks) to medical image analysis.

Comment: Please have a go for transfer learning. I am currently working it and had a better accuracy boost as well.